# I am trying to map over an object to display the object properties, only what I have done is causing the information to populate 4 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, map-function

I have an upcomingEvent object that has properties. I am trying to iterate over those properties to display them in the browser. The issue I have run into is it is  populating the browser 4 times with the information in the map. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the main component EventsPage:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import BasicCard from 'pages/EventsPage/EventsCard/index'
import UpcomingEvent from 'pages/EventsPage/UpcomingEvent/UpcomingEvent'
import UpcomingShowFlyerMobile from 'assets/images/flyer-mobile.png'
import EventsHeroImage from 'assets/images/events-hero-image.jpg'
import EventsHeroImageMobile from 'assets/images/events-mobile-hero-image.jpeg'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import useStyles from './styles'

const UPCOMINGEVENT = {
  month: 'JAN',
  day: '24th',
  title: 'WINTER 2020 SHOWCASE',
  time: '6:00PM',
  location: 'THE IRENIC, SAN DIEGO',
  about:
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Consectetur cursus nunc faucibus justo enim, eget dignissim lacus turpis. Tincidunt sed mauris in volutpat. Sapien fringilla libero, facilisis elementum nisi lobortis amet porttitor. Velit risus diam sit feugiat velit enim et, euismod quis.',
}

// const UPCOMINGEVENT = null

const EventsPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(EVENTS)

  const [upcomingEvent, setUpcomingEvent] = useState(UPCOMINGEVENT)
  return (
    <div>
      {/*-------------Mobile View--------------------- */}
      <Grid
        container
        direction='column'
        justify='center'
        alignItems='center'
        spacing={0}
        className={classes.allContainerMobile}
      >
        <div
          className={
            !upcomingEvent
              ? classes.headingContainerMobile
              : classes.headingContainerMobileUpcomingShow
          }
        >
          <div>
            <p className={classes.allEventsTitleMobile}>ALL EVENTS</p>
          </div>
          {upcomingEvent === null ? (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.parentDivImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.ImageDivMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={EventsHeroImageMobile}
                    className={classes.placeHolderImageMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Grid item sm={12} className={classes.gridMobile}>
                <div className={classes.countdownContainerMobile}>
                  <div className={classes.countdownParentMobile}></div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          )}
          <div>
            <p
              className={
                upcomingEvent
                  ? classes.upcominShowMobileUpcomingEvent
                  : classes.upcomingShowMobile
              }
            >
              UPCOMING SHOW
            </p>
          </div>
          {upcomingEvent === null ? (
            <div>
              <div>
                <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsMobile}>
                  NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.flyerImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.upcomingShowParentMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={UpcomingShowFlyerMobile}
                    className={classes.imageStyleMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        {upcomingEvent !== null && (
          <div>
            {Object.entries(upcomingEvent).map(([key, data]) => (
              <UpcomingEvent
                key={key}
                title={upcomingEvent.title}
                day={upcomingEvent.day}
                month={upcomingEvent.month}
                time={upcomingEvent.time}
                location={upcomingEvent.location}
                about={upcomingEvent.about}
              />
            ))}
            <div></div>
          </div>
        )}
        <div>
          <h2
            className={
              upcomingEvent
                ? classes.pastShowsUpcomingMobile
                : classes.pastShowsMobile
            }
          >
            PAST SHOWS
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div className={classes.eventsCardMobile}>
          {events.map(({ month, day, title, time, location }, i) => (
            <BasicCard
              key={`${title}-${i}`}
              month={month}
              day={day}
              title={title}
              time={time}
              location={location}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Grid>
```

and here is the UpcomingEvent component;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import UpcomingShowFlyerDesktop from 'assets/images/flyer-desktop.png'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import useStyles from '../styles'

function UpcomingShow({ title, day, month, time, location, about }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className={classes.upcomingShowsMobile}>
          <div className={classes.titleContainerMobile}>
            <p className={classes.upcomingShowTitleMobile}>{title}</p>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.dateLocationContainerMobile}>
            <p className={classes.upcomingShowDateLocationMobile}>
              {month} {day} |{location}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.aboutContainerMobile}>
            <p className={classes.aboutUpcomingShowMobile}>{about}</p>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.upcomingShowButtonContainerMobile}>
            <button className={classes.upcomingShowButtonMobile}>
              BUY TICKETS
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
export default UpcomingShow
```

Comment: if i understand you  good do you want to display the value of the UpcomingEvent  4 times each time with different Compoenent

Comment: @Hamza Miloud Amar I am trying to display the properties from the object on the upcomingEvents component, but instead of displaying the properties of the object only once when they are called on upcomingEvent component it is displaying everything from the UpcomingEvent object 6 times, I guess one time for every property in the object.

Comment: This line `{Object.entries(upcomingEvent).map(([key, data]) => ( ... ` would cause render 6 instances of component `UpcomingEvent`. That is normal. If you want only 1, then you should not use `map`. Remove map and just write: `<UpcomingEvent title={upcomingEvent.title} ... `

Comment: @Ajeet Shah Thank you, I will try that.